# iTextSharp - Signed Hash

Tags: pdf, hash, itext

I'm developing a WebService where a client could sign a PDF, these are the steps:

1. Client select the pdf to sign
2. the Web Service Extract the hash from the pdf and send it to an External Provider
3. the External Provider sign the hash
4. the External Provider sends back the signed Hash
5. the Web Service include the signed hash back to the pdf
6. the Client have the signed PDF

I'd encounter a big problem trying to insert/update the signed hash into the pdf.

I'm using iTextSharp.

I'd already read the white paper "Digital Signatures for PDF documents" from Bruno Lowagie, and it was a great help, but I can't figure it out how to insert the signed hash, which by the way, is the only thing I have, no certificates, no nothing.

Code to extract hash

```
private string FileHash(byte[] vGblFilePDF) { using (SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider()) { vGblHash = Convert.ToBase64String(sha1.ComputeHash(vGblFilePDF)); } return vGblHash; }
```

Comment: Have you kept the original `PdfStamper` and `SignatureAppearance`? Without at least the pivotal parts of your code, it is hard to help you.

Comment: That's the thing, the provider only ask for the hash. No Signature Appearance, no nothing. 
Basically I extract the hash of the pdf file like this. 
[CODE]
private string FileHash(byte[] vGblFilePDF)
{
 using (SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider())
 {
  vGblHash = Convert.ToBase64String(sha1.ComputeHash(vGblFilePDF));
 }
 return vGblHash;
} 
[/CODE] 
then i send it to the provider trought a WS, adding only a Id number, then the provider send me back (after an identification) the signed hash, wich i have to insert into the pdf. 
I know something is missing. Regards.

Answer (score 2):

According to your comment your current approach is as follows:

> Basically I extract the hash of the pdf file like this.
>
> ```
> private string FileHash(byte[] vGblFilePDF)
> {
>     using (SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider())
>     {
>         vGblHash = Convert.ToBase64String(sha1.ComputeHash(vGblFilePDF));
>     }
>     return vGblHash;
> }
> ```
>
> then i send it to the provider trought a WS, adding only a Id number, then the provider send me back (after an identification) the signed hash, wich i have to insert into the pdf.

**This approach is fundamentally wrong, you already start by calculating the wrong hash!**

You first have to *prepare your PDF*; during this preparation step you add certain structures to the PDF that mark the PDF as containing a signature and reserve a section for the later insertion of a signature container; everything **with the exception of that reserved section** then is to be hashed:

[image: Basic structure of a signed PDF]

(For some backgrounds and pointers to additional literature cf. [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/35131/16096).)

Thereafter a full-blown PKCS#7 / CMS signature container with a signature for that document hash has to be created and inserted in that reserved section.

This is what most of the iText signing code (here in Java) does for you:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0');
// Creating the appearance
PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
appearance.setReason(reason);
appearance.setLocation(location);
appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(36, 748, 144, 780), 1, "sig");
// Creating the signature
ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
ExternalSignature signature = ...;
MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, signature, chain, null, null, null, 0, subfilter);
```

(taken from [C2_01_SignHelloWorld.java](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/tutorial/blob/master/signatures/src/main/java/signatures/chapter2/C2_01_SignHelloWorld.java) equivalent to [C2_01_SignHelloWorld.cs](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itextsharp/tutorial/blob/master/signatures/chapter2/C2_01_SignHelloWorld/C2_01_SignHelloWorld.cs))

You merely need to provide a `ExternalSignature`/`IExternalSignature` implementation communicating with your provider:

```
public interface IExternalSignature {

    /**
     * Returns the hash algorithm.
     * @return  the hash algorithm (e.g. "SHA-1", "SHA-256,...")
     */
    String GetHashAlgorithm();

    /**
     * Returns the encryption algorithm used for signing.
     * @return the encryption algorithm ("RSA" or "DSA")
     */
    String GetEncryptionAlgorithm();

    /**
     * Signs it using the encryption algorithm in combination with
     * the digest algorithm.
     * @param message   the message you want to be hashed and signed
     * @return  a signed message digest
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException
     */
    byte[] Sign(byte[] message);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. And if I understand correctly the line ExternalSignature signature = ...; will be the signed hash. But, in the line MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, signature, chain, null, null, null, 0, subfilter);, i need a certificate (chain variable) wich i don't have. The best aproach is the example on pages 116 - 120 from the IText White Paper, but I missing some data (already talk with my provider). Thanks a Lot for your help!!

Comment: You will need the certificate anyways, either like here explicitly or implicitly by using a signature provider which sends back a full PKCS#7 / CMS signature container already including the signer certificate. The certificate after all indicates the identity of the signer...

Comment: "*And if I understand correctly the line `ExternalSignature signature = ...;` will be the signed hash.*" - Not quite... it will be the instance of a class with a method `byte[] Sign(byte[] message);` which (when called) returns the signature bytes for the hash.